# Large GB arrays on heap/static, macOS and Linux

Tags: c, memory, out-of-memory

I have trouble working with *very* large arrays in C, declared `static` to avoid the stack.    On macOS, I can't even allocate 1GB.  On linux, I can't go beyond 11GB.  (Yes, I really have data sets that are this large.  Given that desktop computers can now have 256GB or more, I would have thought that the C underpinnings would be set up to deal with this much RAM by default.)

I am working on a 64GB Mac Studio, but tried the code under linux, too.  All are latest versions as of Nov 2023, clang 15.0.0 on macos.  gcc 12.3.0 on linux.  `ulimit` tells me that we are unlimited, except for stack size, processes, and file descriptors.)

Basic code that can reliably generate this error (whittled down) follows.  How does one deal with this nowadays?

#### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define SSS 2025L  // at 2025, this dies on macos
#define MB (1024*1024L)
#define DIM (SSS*MB)

static uint8_t storagearray[DIM];


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  memset( storagearray, 1, sizeof storagearray );
  fprintf(stderr, "[clear ok on %ld = %ld B = %ld MB]\n",
      DIM, sizeof(storagearray), sizeof(storagearray)/1024/1024);

  long int sum=0;
  for (long ix=0; ix < DIM; ++ix) sum+= storagearray[ix];

  fprintf(stderr, "[write ok %ld, exit]\n", sum);

  return 0;
}
```

#### Macos

When SSS is 2025L or higher, it flunks maos with one of two errors:

1. bus error (or with the -fsanitize=address, a violation)
2. at invokation (not after running for a while)

```
  dyld[99042]: dyld cache '(null)' not loaded: syscall to map cache into shared region failed
  dyld[99042]: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    Referenced from: <BB88C06F-4A2F-3CCB-8270-8A6D2E5DC717> /Users/ivo/Sync/research/country-climate-data-gridded/econ-activity/nightlites/data/a.out
  Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib' (no such file, no dyld cache)
```

#### Linux

When SSS is 12,000, it says "killed."  When it is 15,000, it says "segfault".

Comment: `static` memory is not on the heap, to use the heap you have to use `malloc` and `free` ..... did you try using them ?

Comment: It depends on how you define "heap", @AhmedAEK.  Stack and heap are not C language concepts, but C implementations for machines with hardware stacks typically do not store objects with static storage duration in stack memory.  If you don't want to consider them to be on the heap either then that's fine, but then you do have to define another category of memory in which they live.

Comment: With that said, objects declared at file scope always have static storage duration.  For them (unlike for block-scope variables) the `static` keyword is about linkage of the identifier, not storage for the object.

Comment: I corrected the question phrasing.  (I meant not on the stack.)

Comment: On the heap (with malloc), even macos has no problem with 50 GB.  so, it's a limitation of `static` in the implementation, at the intersection of the C language and the OS.  sigh...why would a static array then not always be placed into the same memory space as a dynamically allocated array?  presumably just as fast, but without limitation?

Answer (score 2):

> `ulimit` tells me that we are unlimited, except for
> stack size, processes, and file descriptors.)

"unlimited" should not be taken literally.  It means the OS does not impose any *additional* limit on the given resource type, but there are still limits built into the operating system and C implementation, and ultimately you are limited by the machine's hardware.

> I have trouble working with very large arrays in C, declared static to
> avoid the stack.

Declaring your array at file scope is sufficient to give it static storage duration.  Additionally declaring it `static` does not have further implications on where it is stored, at least as far as the C language is concerned.  (The same is not true of variables declared inside functions.)

> On macos, I can't even allocate 1GB. On linux, I
> can't go beyond 11GB.

This is a function of your operating system and C implementation.  Nothing requires your C implementation to be able to support arbitrarily large declared objects.

> How does one deal with this nowadays?

This is again a function of your operating system and C implementation, but it is common that you can allocate larger objects dynamically than you can statically or (especially) automatically.  If you cannot allocate large enough objects statically then dynamic allocation (`malloc` or `calloc`) is your best bet.

Comment: why is it common that static is not smart enough to use the same place in memory as malloc can?

Comment: @ivoWelch, I never said that objects with static storage duration live in a different part of memory than mallocated ones.  That you may be able to allocate larger objects dynamically than your compiler will accept as declared objects is a characteristic of those C implementations themselves, not, generally, of the addresses where objects are located.  To the extent that there is a necessary difference, it arises from `malloc()` needing to use memory that is not already in use for existing objects.